# Converting iPhone code to Android

Tags: android, iphone, user-agent

I put up a problem on Android and didn't get any answer but I've found a similar problem on the iPhone platform with the answer but I don't know how to translate this into Java code. Please can anyone who is well versed in both languages give this a try.

```
NSString* userAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=el&q=Καλημέρα" 
                        stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];

[request setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                 returningResponse:&response
                                             error:&error];


[data writeToFile:@"/var/tmp/tts.mp3" atomically:YES];
```

Comment: This is possible, ill try to have a crack at it eh?

Comment: You would like me to convert some code from 'iPhone' into 'Android', yes?  My rates are very competitive. Give me a call.

Comment: he is trying to get the response from that link using http get right?

Comment: As a mp3? He is trying to translate that text and get back the recording of the translation....

Comment: Why bother learning to program in a different language when you can just post the code and expect someone else to do your work for you! I hope you aren't being paid by someone to do this work....

Comment: No need for the wise cracks, I'm not trying to learn how to program in iPhone. I just needed to know what was being done in the code. You are not compelled to respond.

Comment: @Amanni Why don't you ask the correct question then? The question you appear to want answered is specific to the functioning of the code (going by one of your comments - "does it change the useragent"). What you HAVE asked in your question is in fact for someone to spend considerable time and effort in porting the objective-c code to Java.

Comment: My apologies that's what I wanted to know

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out, (As I understand)

He is trying to download a file form web and saved it to local storage in i-phone,

In android try this code,

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=el&q=Καλημέρα");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/tts.mp3");

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
       int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
       output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Also mention Use-Permission in your Android Manifest.xml file like,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Now, this will store your downloaded mp3 file in external storage.

Comment: Does it say anything about changing the useragent?

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=el&q=Καλημέρα");

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

Then get the file some how here from the response? Sorry no IDE with me atm.

Maybe something like this?

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(response.getEntity().getContent());
```

I have no idea how to parse mp3 files tho?

What about something like

```
InputStream is = response.getEnitity().getContent();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
int current = 0;
while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
   baf.append((byte) current);
}

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
fos.close();
```